# Position highcharts datalabels to the left of positive bars and to the right of negative bars

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

How to customize the datalabel position in highcharts so that negative value labels are placed to the right of the bar and positive are placed to the left?
This is the default layout for the datalabel position:
[image]

And this is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I have tried doing something like this:

```
align: 'bottom',
    inside: true,
         x:{
           formatter: function () {
           this.y  < 0 ? 50 : -50;
         }
     }
```

But in this case, x must be undefined and as it is placing all of the datalabels along the left edge – I was hoping to be able to get the centre of the chart and use this method to place them on the correct side:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Here is a fiddle if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/xxw64cde/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the data labels on load/redraw events - you can calculate their desired position based on the bars positions.

```
  function moveDataLabels() {
   const chart = this;

    chart.series.filter(series => series.type === 'bar' && series.visible).forEach(series => {
      series.points.forEach(point => {
        const dataLabel = point.dataLabel;
        const offset = point.shapeArgs.height + (point.y > 0 ? dataLabel.width : 0);

        dataLabel.attr({
          x: chart.plotWidth - point.plotY - Math.sign(point.y) * offset,
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Attach the function on chart's redraw

```
 chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  events: {
    load: setEx,
    redraw: moveDataLabels
  }
},
```

#### Live example and output

https://jsfiddle.net/4ubeL2x5/

[image: chart with repositioned data labels]

Comment: That works, thank you. For some reason my version of Visual Studio does not recognise the syntax as being correct - I must need to update my intellisense :-)